# Android studio stuck on "Prepare Android drawable importer"

Tags: android-studio

Whenever I want to start Android studio canary, it starts preparing Android drawable importer, and never quits..

I know that it is beta, so unstable, but it just won't go past the preparing fase..

How can I resolve this issue?

I also noticed that windows will lagg heavily when Android studio is preparing Android drawable importer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed it by **deleting**

> android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin

**plugin folder**

`C:\Users\<user name>\.AndroidStudio3.4\config\plugins`

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it by doing this: 
Right click on studio64.exe file -> compatibility tab.

1. Enable compatibility mode for your windows.
2. Execute as administrator.

Comment: Worker for me, after installation i turned off run as admin and compatibility mode. Still works.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by doing the following:

**Disable / Uninstall plugins**
Open your previous Android Studio and disable or (preferrably) uninstall third party plugins.

**Run in compatibility mode**
Right Click on studio64.exe > click properties > compatibility > run compatibility troubleshooter

Answer (score 0):

This plugin contains almost 60MB zipped assets, Android Studio is processing them at first start.

Just delete assets folder from `%ANDROID_STUDIO_CONFIG_DIR%\config\plugins\android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin` path.

Answer (score 0):

Just deleting the plugin from the folder worked for me.
C:\Users<user name>.AndroidStudio<>\config\plugins